# How to check which return statement was executed in a function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return

Hi i have a simple function:

```
def check_val(value):
    if value < 10:
        previous = value
        return previous
    else:
        current  = value + 10
        return current

a = check_val(3)
```

How can I know if `current`  or `previous` was returned?

Comment: You can have your variable name doing : a_as_str, and then compare it to "current"

Comment: what is your desired behavior?

Comment: This should throw an error if you don't have a `value` defined in the global namespace. If you do, you can always check if `a - 10 == value` to see if the `current` was returned or not.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. It *seems* pretty clear to me what OP needs (and at least one other). There *may* be a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your function return a `tuple` with the necessary meta and unpack via sequence unpacking:

```
def check_val(value):
    if value < 10:
        previous = value
        return previous, 'previous'
    else:
        current  = value + 10
        return current, 'current'

a, b = check_val(3)

print(a, b)

3 previous
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't unless you return a tuple with a flag specifying where you exited

```
def check_val(val):
    if value < 10:
        previous = value
        return previous, False
    else:
        current  = value + 10
        return current, True

a, was_current = check_val(3)

print(a, was_current)  # --> 3 False
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you can't do this directly. There is no way of telling which return sent you the value just from the value itself.

You can of course return a tuple, as pointed out within other answers.

In my oppinion though, you should try to decouple checks from other calculations if you are interested in both informations, for it makes it easier to understand the returned value.

Like that, maybe:

```
def check_condition(value):
    if value < 10:
        return True
    return False

def get_result(value, condition):
    if condition:
        return value
    else:        
        return value + 10

val = 5
check_result = check_condition(val)
result = get_result(val, check_result)
```

It's hard to say if that makes sense since I don't know your use case. In your particular example I'd probably stick to the tuple.